# Will the resque queue loads the complete application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memory, resque

I have 16 resque queues and when I try to see the memory allocaton for these queues it is showing like 4% of the memory for each fo these queues. But at that time all these queues are empty. SO, out of 100% of my memory nearly 64% is utilized by the environment load itself. Thats what I feel.

My doubt are
1. Will each of these resque queues loads the complete application into memory separately.

1. If Yes, can I make any change to the resque configuation in such a way that all resque queues use the same environment loaded in a single place in memory.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you are out of luck if you're using Resque. I believe this is why [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) was developed as a *nearly* drop-in replacement for Resque. The author of Sidekiq wrote a [blog post](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/09/16/improving-resques-memory-efficiency/) describing how he improved Resque's memory usage. Here's a little bit from [the Sidekiq FAQs](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/FAQ):

**Why Sidekiq over Multi-threaded Resque?**

> Back at Carbon Five I worked on improving Resque to use threads
>   instead of forking. That project was the basis for Sidekiq. I would
>   suggest using Sidekiq over that fork of Resque for a few reasons:
>
> - MT Resque was a one-off for a Carbon Five client and is not supported.
>     There are a number of bugs that were not solved, e.g. the web UI's
>     display of worker threads, because they were not important to the
>     client.
> - Sidekiq was built from the ground up to use threads via
>     Celluloid.
> - Sidekiq has middleware, which lets you do cool things in
>     the job lifespan. Resque doesn't support middleware like this
>     natively.

**In short, MT Resque: a quick hack to save one client a lot of money, Sidekiq: the well designed solution for the same problem.**